# I have a out of box file upload control in my sharepoint application. the control works fine in IE 8 except windows 10 edge browser

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-edge

I have a out of box file upload control in my sharepoint application. the control works fine in IE 8
 except windows 10 edge browser.

Comment: the control is not displaying on Edge browser

Comment: Without any error message or code, we can't help you.. Because is an out of box component, I think you have to see with author of this component

Comment: At-least mention which SharePoint version...One more suggestion try this  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: If it works in IE8 but not in Edge, it's probably using old-fashioned IE-specific JavaScript syntax or ActiveX controls. In that case, it will never work in Edge; you're better off rewriting the control to make it work in modern browsers.